# FusionChart is not displaying in iPad Phonegap Project

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cordova, fusioncharts

Hi I'm developing a Phonegap based iOS Project in which i'm having a section where a fusionchart has to display, if i run my index.html in browser it is working fine but in iPad with in that section Graph is loading message will come but the graph is not at all visible even if i wait for more than 10 mins.
How to render this fusion-chart in my iPad screen.Any help is thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sure you must be using the JavaScript files from FusionCharts XT release.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how you are rendering it or how much data you are rendering, however, I have created a small sample which works in XCode iPad simulator.

Please find the sample project from: http://www.sudipto.net/download/ios/phonegap/app/fusioncharts/fusionchartsxt.zip

NOTE: I have mostly followed the steps from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%2520Started%2520with%2520iOS

and

http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/FirstChart/UsingPureJS.html

Answer (score 0):

If viable at this stage: Uninstall Phonegap and replace it with Apache Cordova. Phonegapp is a dodgy and profit driven release of the most excellent Cordova by Apache ...

[Apache Cordova website](http://cordova.apache.org/)

Answer (score -1):

cordov Framework Missing IN This